# Data connection works without a data plan

Tags: settings, mobile-data, samsung-galaxy-s-6, 4g

I am trying to control my screen time by disabling internet access. I have filtered my mac address so the wifi does not work.

So I turned off WiFi and a 4G LTE symbol is shown in the notification bar. When I went to test out the internet, the only websites that worked were ones with google.com as the domain (mind you WiFi is off).

How is it possible that a website can work despite the fact that there is no data plan or WiFi connection? Is there a way I can turn this feature off? I know I can go to settings and turn mobile data off, but I want a "permanent" and less accessible solution.

Ps: I have tried app blockers, they are not an ideal solution for me.

Comment: Hi, I don't know what carrier and plan you're using, but maybe they have (usually more expensive) pay-as-you-use mobile data (with limited purposes, like only for Google search). You might want to check this with your carrier.

Comment: I got T-Mobile but I am unsure which it is. I did not pay for my phone plan so I will check

Comment: Disabling mobile data is difficult on 4G as the phone itself uses data for phone calls (VoLTE) as on LTE there is no other way to make phone calls.